# Regular expression help parsing SQLIO output

Tags: regex

I've been working on a regular expression to parse the output of a series of SQLIO runs. I've gotten pretty far, but not quite there yet. I'm seeking a 100% regex solution and no pre-manipulation of the input.  Could anyone assist with a little guidance with the following regular expression:

```
.*v(?<SQLIOVersion>\d\.\d).*\n.*\n(?<threads>\d*)\s.*for\s(?<Seconds>\d+).*\n.*using\s(?<clustersize>[0-9]*)KB.*\n.*\n.*size:\s(?<currentfilesize>\d+).*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\s(?<IOs>\d*\.\d*).*\n.*\s(?<MBs>\d*\.\d*).*\n.*\n.*\s(?<MinLatency_ms>\d+).*\n.*\s(?<AvgLatency_ms>\d+).*\n.*\s(?<MaxLatency_ms>\d+).*\n.*\n.*\n\%\:..(?<ms>\d*\s+)*
```

Here's a snippet of the output - note the headers, which change during the SQLIO batch run: [File](http://www.sovs.net/public/sqlio_test_file.txt)

Comment: What problems are you having? /(?<ms>\d*\s+)*/ doesn't mean what you may think, it will only get you the last value and not a list of values. You might want something like /(?<ms>(?:\d+\s+)+)/. What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Well I wasn't getting all the entries which Allan has identified in his answer. In regards to the ms in the histogram, I am actually getting a list of values with the specified expression (couldn't get your suggestion to work?). However the last value also includes CR LF for some reason. Haven't quite figured that one out. I'm using expresso as editor.

Comment: Try changing `\%\:..(?<ms>\d*\s+)*` to `%:(?<ms> +\d+)+`.  You seem to be assuming `\s` only matches spaces, but it matches linefeeds, too (along with several other characters).  And just FYI, `%` and `:` don't need to be escaped, but that wasn't doing any harm.

Comment: Excellent - Your suggestion works very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be here:

```
    using 8KB random IOs
    buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
```

After capturing the cluster size, you use `.*\n` to consume the second line before going on to capture the file size, but sometimes there's a third line:

```
    using 8KB random IOs
    enabling multiple I/Os per thread with 8 outstanding
    buffering set to use hardware disk cache (but not file cache)
```

I added `(?:.*\n)?` to the relevant section of the regex, and now it matches all 36 entries.

I know you want to go 100% regex, but have you considered writing the regex in extended format with comments (i.e., IgnorePatternWhitespace mode)?  I would also recommend using more literal text in the regex to make it easier to follow.  For example,

```
(?<threads>\d+) threads? reading for (?<Seconds>\d+) secs.*\n
```

instead of

```
(?<threads>\d*)\s.*for\s(?<Seconds>\d+).*\n
```

Unreadable code is unmaintainable code, and regexes need all the help they can get. :-/

Comment: How could I have missed that one. Thanks! 
I'll have to look into the more reading friendly formats. I definately will not understand my own expression in 2-3 weeks :)

Answer (score 0):

The hell with counting lines, as long as the order doesn't change you can do the following. Oh, and using /x for big regex helps. ;)

```
qr§
^sqlio\s+v(?<SQLIOVersion>\d+\.\d+)

(?> # atomic match, dont backtrack in here when matched
.{0,400}? # dont match so far that we can get the next result
(?<threads>\d+)\s+thread)

(?>.{0,400}?
\b for\s+(?<Seconds>\d+)\s*sec)

(?>.{0,400}?
\b using\s+(?<clustersize>\d+)\s*KB)

(?>.{0,400}?
\b size:\s+(?<currentfilesize>\d+))

(?>.{0,400}?
\b IOs/sec\D*(?<IOs>\d+\.\d+))

(?>.{0,400}?
\b MBs/sec\D*(?<IOs>\d+\.\d+))

(?>.{0,400}?
\b Min_Latency\D*(?<MinLatency_ms>\d+))

(?>.{0,400}?
\b Avg_Latency\D*(?<AvgLatency_ms>\d+))

(?>.{0,400}?
\b Max_Latency\D*(?<MaxLatency_ms>\d+))

(?>.{0,400}?
^\%:\s*(?<ms>(?:\d+\s+)+))

§mixs
```

PCRE/Perl qr§§ used for quoting.